# HTML5 and a sample RTP Stream?

Tags: html, streaming, rtp

I'm making a website in html5 that needs to play an rtp stream, but When I run it, I dont get anything, and I'm not sure if its my browser (safari 5), my rtp server, or the html code that is the problem. :P does anyone know of a sample rtp stream I could use to test the HTML and my browser?  Thanks Beforehand!

Cheers,
Lukas

Comment: did you ever come across a url? need one also

Answer (score 1):

If you want help with some code, you'll need to show it to us!

Regardless, understand that HTML5 support is browser specific.  You will run into issue.  Beyond streaming protocols, there are also CODEC specific issues, which is what I would guess you are experiencing--a common problem.

Ensure you are encoding the stream with h.264 "Baseline Profile".

Answer (score 1):

*Raw* RTP support is not likely to be included in the implementations of the web browsers as for example discussed in the [Chromium Bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25573). The status of that issue is now **WontFix (Closed)**.

But instead it looks like the web browsers support it in a form of WebRTC [RTCRtpReceiver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpReceiver)
and it's support looks quite promising

[image: screenshot]

So I guess if using HLS is not an option for you, you should consider switching to WebRTC instead.